# Change MenuItem text in onMenuItemSelected

Tags: android, menu

I'm trying to change dynamically the text of one of my button in my FabSpeedDial. When the user tap on a specific menu of this FAB, I want to change the text of this menu item but it doesn't work, nothing change...

```
           @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_one) {
                 menuItem.setTitle(getString(R.string.my_new_text)); // doesn't work
            } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_two) {

            } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_three) {

            }
            return false;
        }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: you need to invalidate the menu I think for it to take effect `invalidateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: it doesn't work :/ I don't know if its related to the component FabSpeedDial.

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

after `menuItem.setTitle("Any title");` to populate changes

Comment: it doesn't work :/ I don't know if its related to the component FabSpeedDial.

Answer (score 0):

your should invalidate the menu so that it will have an impact on UI.

```
menuItem.setTitle(getString(R.string.my_new_text));
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: it doesn't work :/ I don't know if its related to the component FabSpeedDial.

Comment: i didn't get you. you want to change the menu title when the user clicks on a FAB. Is it so?

Comment: It's a fabspeeddial, in which I've 3 menu items. I want to change (to explain it simply) the first item's text with a specific text but it doesn't work.